# Cisco ASA5510: command 'static' is unrecognized

Tags: cisco, command-line-interface

Greetings Experts,

I'm setting up a static NAT from outside to inside on my Cisco ASA5510, something like this:

```
# static (inside,outside) 123.45.67.89 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.255  
static (inside,outside) 123.45.67.89 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.255  
 ^  
ERROR: % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

So then I try this to get some help:

```
# static ?  
ERROR: % Unrecognized command
```

How can 'static' be an unrecognized command?

I'm referencing this documentation:
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa71/configuration/guide/cfgnat.html

Some more info:

```
# show version

Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance Software Version 7.2(2)
Device Manager Version 5.2(2)

Compiled on Wed 22-Nov-06 14:16 by builders
System image file is "disk0:/asa722-k8.bin"
Config file at boot was "startup-config"

xxxxxxxxx-fw up 14 days 17 hours

Hardware:   ASA5510, 256 MB RAM, CPU Pentium 4 Celeron 1600 MHz
Internal ATA Compact Flash, 256MB
BIOS Flash M50FW080 @ 0xffe00000, 1024KB

Encryption hardware device : Cisco ASA-55x0 on-board accelerator (revision 0x0)
                             Boot microcode   : CNlite-MC-Boot-Cisco-1.2
                             SSL/IKE microcode: CNlite-MC-IPSEC-Admin-3.03
                             IPSec microcode  : CNlite-MC-IPSECm-MAIN-2.04
 0: Ext: Ethernet0/0         : address is xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, irq xx
 1: Ext: Ethernet0/1         : address is xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, irq xx
 2: Ext: Ethernet0/2         : address is xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, irq xx
 3: Ext: Ethernet0/3         : address is xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, irq xx
 4: Ext: Management0/0       : address is xxxx.xxxx.xxxx, irq xx
 5: Int: Not used            : irq xx
 6: Int: Not used            : irq xx

Licensed features for this platform:
Maximum Physical Interfaces : Unlimited
Maximum VLANs               : 50
Inside Hosts                : Unlimited
Failover                    : Disabled
VPN-DES                     : Enabled
VPN-3DES-AES                : Enabled
Security Contexts           : 0
GTP/GPRS                    : Disabled
VPN Peers                   : 250
WebVPN Peers                : 2

This platform has a Base license.

Serial Number: xxxxxxxxxxx
Running Activation Key: xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx
Configuration register is 0x1
Configuration has not been modified since last system restart.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you entered those commands directly in 'enable' mode. You probably just need to enter configure mode.

```
ASA5510-01# configure terminal
```

or as a shortcut

```
ASA5510-01# conf t
```

Once you are in configure mode, the prompt and static command will look like this:

```
ASA5510-01(config)# static ? 
configure mode commands/options:
  (  Open parenthesis for (<internal_if_name>,<external_if_name>) pair where
     <internal_if_name> is the Internal or prenat interface and
     <external_if_name> is the External or postnat interface
```

And from there, any configuration commands should work.

Comment: +1. Also he could just hit question mark at the prompt he was at to give him a list of valid commands.